# Merge Videos in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, video, video.js, serverless

I wrote a web app that gives the ability to merge several videos into a single (split-screen) video. I am using video.js and the [video-stream-merger](https://github.com/t-mullen/video-stream-merger) to merge the different videos together. I merge the media streams while playing the videos and capture them by using a MediaRecorder. The user can configure the size and position of each video. This works fine on my Notebook. 
Unfortunately, this doesn't work for older clients and slower phones, so I decided to do the merging server-side using firebase functions. Is it possible to capture and merge the media streams in a firebase function? I know that is not the purpose of media streams, but I thought I could make it work somehow. Is there any better way to merge the videos using node.js? At the time I call the merge function, the single video files are already stored at the firestore.

What is the best approach to merge those videos?

Thank you & best regards,